# How to convert a method which return null to "null-safety."

Tags: flutter, dart

In my old project, I used a method to perform get operation in dart, where I used to return null if the output was not valid.

My code -

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> get(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: basicHeaderInfo()
    );
   
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      ErrorResponse res = ErrorResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return null;
    } else {
      ErrorResponse res = ErrorResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      ToastMessage.error(res.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My Error response class -

```
class ErrorResponse {
  String message;
  String errors;

  ErrorResponse({
    this.errors,
    this.message,
  });

  factory ErrorResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ErrorResponse(
      errors: json["errors"],
      message: json["message"],
    );
  }
}
```

Those were doing best before the null safety,but recently I decided to move in null safety, and my true education just started.
In my `get` method, I am facing an error which flashing an error message

```
A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'get' because it has a return type of 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

Don't know how I will deal with it.
And in Class, there is another error message

```
"The parameter 'errors' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
```

I solved it by this way -

```
class ErrorResponse {
  String message;
  String errors;

  ErrorResponse({
    this.errors = "",
    this.message = "",
  });

  factory ErrorResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ErrorResponse(
      errors: json["errors"],
      message: json["message"],
    );
  }
}
```

Don't know this is Conventional Or Unconventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?>
String? message;
String? errors;
```

Read these articles:

https://dart.dev/null-safety

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: I tried this way, and it's causing another problem, when I am trying to use the method,like ths = Map<String, dynamic> mapResponse = await ApiMethod.get(ApiUrls.url1,)

error message flashing = <Map<string,dynamic>?> can not assign to <Map<string,dynamic>>

Comment: The error message is clearly explaining the motive, you cannot set a value which accepts null to one variable that doesn't. Have you read the articles I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

The best option which I can think of in this scenario will be to

```
throw Exception;
```

And use exception handling (try and catch) in the receiving code.
The other option will be to return an empty object or string and check it later in the code.

Comment: yes, I am using this way, return {}; instead of return null; 
question is, is it a conventional way?

Comment: Yes it's the conventional way.

Comment: If there is an error throw exception else just return and empty object.